# Owl Carousel .В поле вводится номер слайда, при нажатии на кнопку слайдер должен переключиться на этот слайд

Tags: javascript, jquery, owl-carousel

```
    <header>
       <input><button>Start</button> 
        <div class="container">
            <ul>
                <li><a href="#slideshow">Главная</a></li>
                <li><a href="#services">Услуги</a></li>
                <li><a href="#portfolio">Портфолио</a></li>
                <li><a href="#prices">Цены</a></li>
                <li><a href="#contacts">Контакты</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </header>

           var owl = $('.owl-carousel');
owl.on('initialized.owl.carousel', function() {
  console.log('установлен');
});
        $('.lp-slider2').owlCarousel({
            items: 1,
            nav: true,
            navText: ['<i class="fa fa-chevron-left"></i>', '<i class="fa fa-chevron-right"></i>'],
            animateOut: 'fadeOut',

       margin:10,
    responsive:{
        0:{
            items:6
        },
        600:{
            items:5
        },            
        960:{
            items:3
        },
        1200:{
            items:1
        }
    }
    }).on('resize.owl.carousel', function() {
  console.log('resized');
}).on('translated.owl.carousel', function() {
  console.log('слайд прееключен');
});

    });
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

У Owl Carousel довольно слабый функционал для реализации такой задачи, но если слайдер будет соответствовать условиям ниже, все работает безотказно.

Условия:

1. Не устанавливать `loop:true`, иначе нумерация слайдов сбивается и получается полная неразбериха.
2. Указывать `items:1`, иначе указанное число в `input.slide` будет не
   номером слайда, а номером страницы.

```js
var owl = $('.owl-carousel');
owl.owlCarousel({
  items: 1,
  nav: true,
  dots: true,
  startPosition: 0,
  rewind: true
});

$('button.slide').on('click', function() {
  var slide = parseInt($('input.slide').val()) || 1;
  owl.trigger('to.owl.carousel', slide - 1);
});
```

```css
.item {
  height: 100px;
  background: #000;
  color: #fff;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://owlcarousel2.github.io/OwlCarousel2/assets/owlcarousel/assets/owl.theme.default.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="https://owlcarousel2.github.io/OwlCarousel2/assets/owlcarousel/assets/owl.carousel.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://owlcarousel2.github.io/OwlCarousel2/assets/owlcarousel/owl.carousel.js"></script>
<div class="owl-carousel">
  <div class="item">1</div>
  <div class="item">2</div>
  <div class="item">3</div>
  <div class="item">4</div>
  <div class="item">5</div>
</div>
<input type="number" class="slide" />
<button class="slide">go to slide</button>
```